# Insert hidden text inside selectbox option

Tags: php, html-select, hidden

I have a selectbox that displays name and surname for a list of people. But I want to add an id for each of them and make it invisible. 
EX. if we have **John Smith** with **ID 001** I want to write **John Smith:001** , but it should be seen as **John Smith**. It is important that the id is not only unseen but also doesn't take up any space.

This is my code:

```
$result = pg_query(connect(), "SELECT id, name, surname FROM person ORDER BY name ASC, surname ASC");
    $person = pg_fetch_all($result);
    echo '<select value="Person" name="person">';
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($person); $i++) {
                $person = $person[$i]['name'].' '.$person[$i]['surname'];
                echo "<option>".$person."<span hidden>:".$person[$i]['name']."</option>";   }       
    echo '</select>';
```

however, this isn't working because the id remains visible

Comment: why? can't you just use like a `data` attribute

Comment: Do `<select name="person"><option value="{Persons_Name}_{id value you want}">{Persons name}</option>`

Comment: @Rasclatt: I will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting value with combined name and id (further to my comment):

```
<?php
$result = pg_query(connect(), "SELECT id, name, surname FROM person ORDER BY name ASC, surname ASC");
$person = pg_fetch_all($result); ?>
<select name="person">
<?php
     for($i=0; $i<sizeof($person); $i++) {
            $name = $person[$i]['name'].' '.$person[$i]['surname']; ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $name.":".$person[$i]['id']; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
<?php
} ?>  
</select>
```

**Gives you something like:**

```
Array
    (
        [person] => doug johnson:1
    )
```

Comment: To expand the answer (though both answers given were very good), in case we have compound names and / or surnames (ex. Hose Miguel San Roman), the id can be used as a search key because we wouldn't know where the name ends and the surname begins. As the answers suggest, we can insert the ID in the value so that it won't be visible but will be posted anyway. Using a delimiter (I chose ':' but whatever), the id can be separated. Also, i noticed that for some reason, compound names won't be fully read if there are spaces in the VALUE string. you can use str_replace or preg_replace to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use value of option to contain both name and id with a delimiter. And while reading you can split it again.

`<option value="$person[$i]['name']:$person[$i]['id']">`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to keep the value different and the caption different.
So, the code should be:
Let me make it simpler $name is the full name of the person and $id is his id.

```
<option value="<?php echo $name.":".$id?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>
```

Looks like the job can be done a bit cleaner. But anyways the point is you can use the value attribute to send different value to the server than what the user sees.

BTW, Keep in mind that the user can always see the value by seeing the source code in the browser. (if that is not what you want then you'll have to do the change of value part in the php code otherwise this code is good to go)

Comment: Nice to point out that the ID can be seen. However, this is not an issue in this specific case. The ID was redundant to the user, that's why I wanted to hide it. But it's not a problem if they see it (except for aesthetically speaking)

Comment: @amygrimaldi I expected that. But it was just a small 'keep in mind' part if you would have wanted the id to be unseen by the user. As your question didn't mention anything like that I thought better I would make it a bit clearer.